# How do I hide the headline when the content underneath it is not visible

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an application in JavaScript with a very long list of 'Day-items', separated by a header specifying the month, like so:

```
<h3>January 2022</h3>
<div class="item" data-visitors='1'>2022-01-01</div>
<div class="item" data-visitors='0'>2022-01-02</div>
<div class="item" data-visitors='1'>2022-01-03</div>
...etc until
<div class="item" data-visitors='15'>2022-01-31</div>

<h3>February 2022</h3>
<div class="item" data-visitors='0'>2022-02-01</div>
<div class="item" data-visitors='1'>2022-02-02</div>
<div class="item" data-visitors='19'>2022-02-03</div>
...etc until
<div class="item" data-visitors='0'>2022-02-28</div>

<h3>March 2022</h3>
<div class="item" data-visitors='0'>2022-03-01</div>
<div class="item" data-visitors='11'>2022-03-02</div>
<div class="item" data-visitors='5'>2022-03-03</div>
...etc until
<div class="item" data-visitors='2'>2022-03-28</div>
```

The number of items are about 6.500 with some 200 headlines. I purposely do not write my code here as it is messy, and irrelevant in my opinion. It is the produced DOM that is interesting here.

Using filters in (vanilla) JavaScript, based on `data-visitors` value I change some divs to `style.display='none'`. For example, all divs with class 'item' with a `data-visitors` value below 15 will get a `style.display='none'`.

This will practically make the view of the html-file look like this

> #### January 2022
>
> #### February 2022
>
> 2022-02-03
>
> #### March 2022

Here, I would like to hide "January 2022" and "March 2022" headlines (h3's) as there are no items visible for them (HTML-divs still exist but, as mentioned, with a `display:none`). In my application, this list ranges from 2004 to 2022 so there are a lot of empty months.

**My question:** How can I hide the month headers when there is no content underneath them visible any longer?

Due to how theses lists are being dynamically created:

**What I can do**: Add classes, ids, data-attributes etc to both month h3 headlines as well as divs

**What I cannot do**: Wrap h3 and the divs in a wrapping div, or add a wrapping div around all the `<div class='item'>`.

My conclusions, and I am not an experienced programmer in JavaScript: The divs are not children of the h3 so I cannot use anything like that. Siblings would not work either.

Thinking in pseudo-code, I would imagine putting a `id='2022-02'` on the h3-tag, and some `data-attr-year-month-item='2022-02'` on the div's. Then, query something like (this is just make-up-code):

```
if ((document.querySelectorAll("[attr-year-month-item='2022-02']").display=='none').length == (document.querySelectorAll("[attr-year-month-item='2022-02']").length)) {

document.getElementById('2022-02').style.display='none'

}
```

In other words, if the length of the divs that have style.display='none' equals the length of all the divs in that month, then the headline should be hidden.

What I would like help with is, how do I write this if-statement in **vanilla** JavaScript so that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might traverse the items from the bottom to the top, checking if all of the group after `h3` were hidden, then hide the `h3`:

```js
let hideH3 = true;
[...document.querySelectorAll('.item')].reverse()
.forEach(i => {
  const hide = i.dataset.visitors < 15;
  hideH3 &= hide;
  if (hide) i.classList.add('hidden');
  const next = i.previousElementSibling;
  if (next.nodeName == 'H3') {
    if (hideH3) next.classList.add('hidden');
    else hideH3 = true;
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {display:none}
```

```html
<h3>January 2022</h3>
<div class="item" data-visitors='1'>2022-01-01</div>
<div class="item" data-visitors='0'>2022-01-02</div>
<div class="item" data-visitors='1'>2022-01-03</div>

<h3>February 2022</h3>
<div class="item" data-visitors='0'>2022-02-01</div>
<div class="item" data-visitors='1'>2022-02-02</div>
<div class="item" data-visitors='19'>2022-02-03</div>
<div class="item" data-visitors='0'>2022-02-28</div>

<h3>March 2022</h3>
<div class="item" data-visitors='0'>2022-03-01</div>
<div class="item" data-visitors='11'>2022-03-02</div>
<div class="item" data-visitors='5'>2022-03-03</div>
<div class="item" data-visitors='5'>2022-03-28</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't gotten back to you. This seems to be the correct answer but it is actually doing something more than I anticipated (sorry for the ambiguity). When this function is being called, all 'items' have already been hidden, so this is something I need to do after that. For example, assume that you would only have january with hidden items, february with one item visible and march with only hidden items. How would your code be altered to hide January and March?

Comment: It seemed like removing the lines 'const hide = i.dataset.tornadocount < 15;' and //if (hide) i.classList.add('hidden'); would work but I can't figure out how hideH3 is actually "activated". I am not sure what the &= actually does to the code here.

Comment: @Christoffer, the function does both -- hides the items and headers, so you don't have to loop over twice. If for some reason you have items hidden already, you might remove `if (hide) i.classList.add('hidden');`. `&=` operator is a short hand for `hideH3 = hideH3 & hide;` where `&` is binary `and`.

Comment: Thanks! I see, and this is great although doesn't apply to my situation. For future sake, keep this but you can add this solution perhaps as well:    let hasVisible = false;

   [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')].reverse()
   .forEach(i => {

      if (i.style.display != 'none') { (hasVisible = true) }

      const next = i.previousElementSibling;
      if (next.nodeName == 'H3') {
         if (!hasVisible) next.classList.add('hidden');
         hasVisible = false
      }
   });

Comment: So, your answer is better to keep as the generic solution, but in case someone needs to solve it the way I had to it would be neat to have this in your answer as well (can probably be better coded as well). Thanks! I would not have thought of this answer myself, so this was truly helpful!

Comment: @Christoffer, BTW, `&=` could be replaced with more trivial `*=`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the visibility programatically so why not do this while you are at it? Something like

```
let element = document.getElementByID('firsth3');
let h3 = element;
while ( element.id != 'lastdiv' ) {
  element = element.nextElementSibling;
  if ( element.tagName == 'H3' ) {
    h3 = element;
  } else if ( element.dataset.visitors > 15 ) {
    element.styyle.display = 'block';
    h3.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

where you give everything a display: none initially and mark the first and last elements with ids.

Comment: I haven't had time to test this yet. I am having a bit of a hard time figuring out the logic of it, but I will try it out.